# Multiple drop down lists with the same behaviour with jquery

Tags: jquery

This is suppose to be a very simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have forms over data type scenario, where someone can enter information about the services offered. So the form looks like this

1. [DropDown: serviceType] [DropDown: services] [TextBox: info]
2. [DropDown: serviceType] [DropDown: services] [TextBox: info]
   ...
   5 [DropDown: serviceType] [DropDown: services] [TextBox: info]

I want the corresponding service list populated based on the selection Service Type list, so I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select#serviceType").change(function() {
            var serviceId = $("#serviceType > option:selected").attr("value");

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "GetServicesByServiceType/" + serviceId,
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var options = '';
                    for (index in data) {
                        var service = data[index];
                        options += "<option value='" + service.ServiceId + "'>" + service.Name + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("#services").removeAttr('disabled').html(options);
                }
            }
            );
        });
    });
```

I am having the following problems:

1. I am referencing a specific element ID, instead I would want that to be figured out programatically, since number of elements varies.
2. I want the services drop down to refresh on select change as well as well initially on load

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you post your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to figure it out. This will update each cascading drop down list within a TR when the value changes as well as run this on load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var populateDropDowns = function() {
            var currentDropdown = $(this);
            var serviceId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/GetServicesByServiceType/" + serviceId,
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var options = '';
                    for (index in data) {
                        var service = data[index];
                        options += "<option value='" + service.ServiceId + "'>" + service.Name + "</option>";
                    }

                    currentDropdown.closest('tr').find("select.services").html(options);
                }
            }
            );
        };

        $('select.currentServices').each(populateDropDowns);
        $('select.currentServices').change(populateDropDowns);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that each triplet of ServiceType, Service, Info 
is encased in its own `<div>` container like so:

```
<div>
    <select class="type">
        <option value="type1">ServiceType 1</option>
        <option value="type2">ServiceType 2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="service"/>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

As you can see the ServiceType `<select>` is marked with the `class` attribute to make it easier to target. So assuming all your ServiceType lists have `class=type`, you can now write

```
$(function(){
    $('select.type').change(function(){
        var serviceId=$(this).val(); //'this' keyword refers to 
                                     //the dropdownlist that triggered the event
        $.ajax({
                ... //other stuff
                success: function(data){
                             ... //parse data
                             /*siblings('select') will select all
                               the other <select> elements in the same container,
                               which now happens to be the <select class='service'/>
                               inside the parent <div>*/
                             $(this).siblings('select').removeAttr('disabled').html(options);
                         }
        });
    });
});
```

To have your service dropdownlist refresh on change should be pretty trivial by now:

```
$('select.service').change(function(){
    ... //do stuff here
});
```

To do anything on page load, simply include your statement inside the

```
$(function(){
    ...//will execute after dom is ready, ie after page loads
});
```

block

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I almost got it to work, but a few things are not working still:

1. $(this).siblings('select') doesn't work for me, because each drop down list is inside its own TD column. I tried putting the div inside of TR, but it doesn't work:

<tr>
  <div>
  <td>select 1</td>
  <td>select 2</td>
  </div>
</tr>

2. So now this work on change of the "type" drop down list. I also want it to work on load, (since on load one option is already pre-selected). Can I do that without re-writing the same code under $(function){ .. }); ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: $(this).siblings('select') didn't work because in the current context $(this) refers to the JSON request, since it's inside .$ajax call

Comment: yeah, i messed the this reference inside the ajax call :)